# how to cut rest of the string after a special character and assign result to a variable in shell script

Tags: bash

Example:

```
var1=$(</bin/file1.txt)
```

Say `var1` contains, `abcd.123`

```
var2 = $var1 | cut -f1 -d"."
```

`var2` should be `abcd`, but in shell script it is not working for me.
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: You need `var2=$(echo $var1 | cut -f -d".")`

Comment: Your example (`var` read from file) suggests, that `var1` can have multiple lines. Do you only want the first part of the first line, or do you want the first parts of all the lines?

Comment: hi @WalterA, file contains only single line

Answer (score 5):

You can use parameter expansion transformations; no need for external programs:

```sh
var1=abcd.123
var2=${var1%%.*}
echo "$var2"
```

will print out `abcd`.

More details at the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could hep you:

```
var1="abcd.123"
var2=$(echo ${var1} | cut -f1 -d".")
echo ${var2}
```

will give you output:

```
abcd
```

Comment: Please quote `echo ${var1}` and `echo ${var2}`, I have `var1="Look out for *."`

Answer (score 0):

Using bash regex matching and the result is already in a var:

```
$ [[ $var1 =~ ^[^.]* ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH}"
abcd
```